# vim - execute range of lines as shell, output in same buffer

Tags: shell, vim

Let's say I'm in a buffer like this, on line 4, I want to run line 1 to 2 and have the output in the same buffer on line 4 (where cursor is):

```
echo "Testing"
echo "more testing"

# and here I want the output from running lines 1 to 2
```

...I know I can do `1,2w !sh` to run lines 1 and 2 and have the output shown in whatever that temporary buffer is. But, how do I get into my actual buffer for later editing?

(And the same thing to work with visual mode selected text, not just with line ranges given by numbers.)

Comment: his Q  **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related sites 
http://vi.stackexchange.com OR http://superuser.com  . Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. . Good luck

Comment: A terrible hack, but which works for this case and can be modified to match most cases:  `:1,3! tee /dev/stderr | sh`.  This works for visual mode selected text as well, but requires that the output goes immediately after the shell commands.

Comment: your hack didn't do what I wanted (ite replaced my entire buffer with the output) but I think it let me tot eh right solution, thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were using `:w !...` (`:help :w_c`), but you probably want `:!` (`:help :!`):

```
gg       - go to top
Vj       - select the two lines
y        - yank into a buffer
4gg      - go to 4th line
V        - select it
p        - paste over it
gv       - reselect the pasted range
:!sh<CR> - execute in shell and replace
```

or, trusting ex commands more,

```
:4d
:1,2y
:3pu
:4,5!sh
```

NB: `!sh` is in most cases equivalent to `!`, as `!` will call your default shell.

Comment: Thx for the solution, but its way too much work to worth doing/learning... what I wanted was to maybe be able to replace `w` from `1,2w !sh` with something else that would either spill the results at current cursor position, or in a new buffer... I need to play with that output, edit it, maybe extract new commands from it and then repeat, the workflow I'm having now with Sublime + ShellCommand, but want to have this when ssh-ing on any random server (so "virgin" vim with no plugin and default or someone else's vim config)

Comment: Too much work? Most of this is just so your original code is not destroyed in the process; the only really important command here is `:!`. Also, there's little reason why you can't copy your own .vimrc to the server, or load a macro from a file - or even use `sshfs` to use your own Vim on the server (unless you are sudoing).

Comment: ok, couldn't find anything that does the right thing and is less awkward so I'm accepting your answer. visual mode selection + `:!sh` does the right thing (plus the annoying yank and paste routine... me lazy... but if I weren't so lazy I'd use smth else than stock vim so that's life I guess...)

Answer (score 0):

Yey! Found it. In case anyone else needs this exact same hack on a virgin/foreign vim (plugin-less or someone else's server/config):

`:1,2r !sh %`

(yeah, output goes after commands, or technically the commands are replaced with their echo but whatever, not at cursor position, but good enough for me to replicate my Sublime + SublimeCommand workflow in vim :) )

Comment: I get `E172: Only one file name allowed` when I execute your command. The syntax doesn't make sense.

Comment: yes, sorry, wrote in wrong order, `:r1,2 !sh %` instead of `:1,2r !sh %`

Comment: The executes the _entire_ buffer in the shell, and inserts all of its output after line `2`. Not what you've asked for, right?

Comment: actually worse, it take the entire file (if buffer was modified since last save modifications are ignored, and I was working on a file with last lines added after last save and this is what confused me)... guess @Amadan's solution is what makes sense